# how can I specify a list on the command line

Tags: python, zsh, fb-hydra

I have the following configuration with hydra:

```
data_files: null
theta: 0.2
use_weights: true
```

I can override this as:

```
python -m apps.test_hydra data.data_files=x
```

However, when I try to specify a list as:

```
python -m apps.test_hydra data.data_files=[x,y]
```

Then I get the following error:

```
zsh: no matches found: data.data_files=[x,y]
```

I am not sure if this is some issue with the zsh shell or hydra issue

Comment: zsh is interpreting `[` and `]` before exec-ing python. Try specifying your list of files as `date.data_files=x,y,z,`

Comment: I tried that and that gives the error: `hydra.errors.OverrideParseException: mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting {':', BRACKET_OPEN, BRACE_OPEN, FLOAT, INT, BOOL, NULL, UNQUOTED_CHAR, ID, ESC, WS, QUOTED_VALUE, INTERPOLATION}`

Comment: @JamesMcPherson ok, it seems doing something like: `data.data_files=\[x,u\]` helps.

Comment: BTW, this isn't just a zshism: you'd get similar behavior from bash if you turned on the `failglob` option (or your argument would silently disappear with `nullglob`); using the `[x,y]` unquoted when you mean the expression to become part of a literal argument isn't good practice in _any_ shell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wrap the string in quotes to avoid `[` being interpreted as a glob expression.

```
python -m apps.test_hydra 'data.data_files=[x,y]'
```

On a [hydra github issue](https://github.com/facebookresearch/hydra/issues/1926#issuecomment-996096912), they use the following syntax. You might have to do something similar.

```
$ python -m apps.test_hydra 'data@data_files=[x, y]'
```

Comment: Nice. Like the quotes option.

Comment: This is documented in Hydra's command line grammar page.
https://hydra.cc/docs/advanced/override_grammar/basic/#dictionaries-and-lists

Answer (score 2):

Use " \ " before special characters.

```
python -m apps.test_hydra data.data_files=\[x,y\]
```

Comment: You _could_ do that, surely, but quoting those characters is arguably easier to read. Backslash escapes are contextually dependent -- f/e, they're literal in single-quoted contexts, and can need to be doubled when inside of backticks; quotes don't have as many "gotchas" associated.